# Next on generators doesn't resume with last call

Tags: python, python-3.x, generator

Why the second `next` doesn't return `"bye"` ?

```
def salute():
    yield "hello"
    yield "bye"


def greet_me():
    print(next(salute()))
    print(next(salute()))

greet_me()
```

Output :

> hello
>
> hello

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because you're creating a *new* generator each time you call `salute()`. Create the generator *once* and *then* call `next` on it to get both yields to yield their value:

```
def greet_me():
    gen = salute()    # create the generator
    print(next(gen))  # start it, goes to the first yield
    print(next(gen))  # resume it, goes to second yield
```

Calling `greet_me` now prints the expected results.

Comment: feel bad for asking now :(

Comment: Never feel bad about asking a question!

Comment: @Oleg agree with Rolf, we've all been there and felt that :)